Are old users will be re-grouped or effected after modifying a running AB Testing in Firebase?
There is a running AB testing in Firebase. It has 4 variants A,B,C,D. The weight is 25% per variant. After 15 days running, I want to add a variant E.
The question is whether the old users in A-D group will be effected or re-grouped? Does the Firebase refresh the user buckets?
For example, there is a user who gets A in the first installation. After I adding the variant E, whether the user will get B or C or D or E?
Thanks.
